# How to receive pdf file from intent filter - Android

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-pendingintent, intentfilter

I have build a PDF Reader which i want to open pdf from any where from phone Ex. Whatsapp, File Manager.

It is working when i open a pdf from google file manager and when i open it from default file manager it crashes

shows this error

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

App Manifest File

```
        <activity
        android:name=".PDF_Viewer"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:mimeType="application/pdf" />

        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:scheme="file"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\.pdf" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\.pdf" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\.pdf" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

I am receiving intent in PDF Viewer Activity like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Uri pdf = (Uri) bundle.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Comment: Post more code as this bundle comes from somewhere. And bundle==null is told by your NullPointerException. Check for null before use.

Comment: I have added more code please check it

Comment: You did not add code to check for null before use. Further you did not give extra info. What will you do now bundle==null ?

Comment: i am not checking if the bundle is null before use, If you know how to fix it please help -@blackapps

Comment: Check if the bundle is null before use! Add code! Third time i ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three of your `<intent-filters>` are for `ACTION_VIEW`. [The documentation for `ACTION_VIEW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_VIEW) has:

> Input: `getData()` is URI from which to retrieve data.

So, with that in mind, replace your Java code with:

```java
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri pdf = intent.getData();
```

You might consider examining existing PDF viewer apps to see how they work. There are [many open source ones listed on F-Droid](https://search.f-droid.org/?q=pdf), for example.